# Highstocks : Automatically calculate the difference between two sets of data

Tags: highcharts

I have a Json datas with timestamp where datas are increasing.

It's possible with Highstocks to automaticly calculate the difference between two datas and display this difference with previous data???

For exemple with this file :

```
        [1247875200000, 10],
        [1247961600000, 20],
        [1248048000000, 26],
        [1248134400000, 30],
```

Showing :

```
        1247961600000 -> 10
        1248048000000 -> 6
        1248134400000 -> 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need highstock to do this automatically?  Just diff the numbers yourself and add it as a second series...

Comment: So it's not possible! Thanks!!